# update dart sdk for special project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

when I use the sqflite package I give this error

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.0-1.0.dev.flutter-24c7666def.
>
> Because kojayi_filnal depends on sqflite >=1.3.2-dev.1 which requires
> SDK version >=2.10.2 <3.0.0, version solving failed. pub get failed
> (1; Because kojayi_filnal depends on sqflite >=1.3.2-dev.1 which
> requires SDK version >=2.10.2 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)

How I can update the dart sdk just for this project

Comment: update your pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Tools' -> Flutter -> 'Flutter Upgrade'

Comment: thanks for the answer but this solution update sdk for the special project or not?